# Storing data from a nested firebase object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with an attendance web app which displays information month wise.
Here is my structure of firebase database:[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veu6P.png)

To iterate over the data, i use this:

```
for(i = 0; i<months.length;i++){

    console.log(months[i]);

    var datesRef = firebase.database().ref('students/' + currentStudentSap + '/attendance/' + currentSem + '/' + months[i]);
    datesRef.on('value',function(snapshot){

        var dates = snapshot.val();
        var date = Object.keys(dates);

        for(j=0;j<date.length;j++){

            console.log(date[j]);

            var lectureRef = firebase.database().ref('students/' + currentStudentSap + '/attendance/' + currentSem + '/' + months[i] + "/" + date[j]);
            lectureRef.on('value',function(snapshot){

                var lectures = snapshot.val();
                console.log(lectures, typeof(lectures));

            }); 
        }
    });
}
```

Here is what I get on the console:
[Console Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYZqf.png)

What I want to do now is save these stats in some data structure so that I can use them to produce graphical charts.
For eg: "COSTtheory" is a subject and I want to calculate total conducted lectures and total present lectures for each month, and display month wise statistics (such as percentage attended) in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you insert data in Firebase but i would not iterate thru it like you do.  Instead i would increment the monthly totals i need to make report each time data is inserted, that way i would be able to show live stats (kind of purpose of a live DB).  I would use Firebase database transactions with cloud functions to achieve this.  Transactions ensure data consistency.